# Android - Finish latest Intent from parent

Tags: android, android-activity, parent

My activities sends long-term requests to slow server, so after sends they show "Loading, please wait" activity (with cute pinkish progressbar, white rabbits, etc) this way:

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ~sendRequestThroughRunnable();
    startActivity(new Intent(Activity.this, LoadingActivity.class));    
}
```

Afterward parent activity get exact notification about end of requests through callback functions (from other thread), so my question is, how can i finish (or stop, etc) LoadingActivity from parent activity and get back control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `startActivity()` with `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)`. When it's time to finish the LoadingActivity call `finishActivity(requestCode)`.